# cross-platform iTunes visualizer?

Tags: python, signal-processing, itunes, visualizer

I'd like to make a cross-platform iTunes visualizer (Mac + Windows). I've looked at:

1. [Quartz Composer](http://www.cybero.co.uk/QuartzComposer/examples/jelly.html), which only runs on Mac OS, and appears to consist of dragging boxes around. I'd like to be able to actually program.
2. [VizKit](http://www.imagomat.de/vizkit/), which seems kind of heavy, and doesn't come with any easy-to-modify sample projects.

Can someone point me to some resources for getting a quick start? Extra points for Python/Processing.org.

Comment: Are you looking to make a visualizer that works in itunes like the built in visualizations, a plug-in that launches a separate visualizer, or a standalone music visualizer that plays mp3s?

Comment: @Lonnen - I want to make a visualizer that works in itunes like the built-in ones.